# JFrame error. Error in entering data into datebase using GUI

Tags: java, mysql, swing, nullpointerexception

I know there are a lot of answers given to this error but I couldn't find the solution. I've found the line generating the error. `String dbop="INSERT INTO employees.workers (ID,First_Name) VALUES ('6',"+name+"')";` is generating the error. the GUI runs smoothly but it should also insert the data in `employee.workers` database (Database: Employee, Table: workers) but it generates a lot of errors I'll paste errors.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication13.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:78)
at javaapplication13.NewJFrame.access$100(NewJFrame.java:5)
at javaapplication13.NewJFrame$2.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Whenever I execute the program it shows the GUI pop-up that I generated using swing but whatever I enter something in `JTextField` and press the button to enter data in the database. these errors come right to my face. I've tried specifying the exact syntax of MySQL but same errors

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        String name=input.getText();
        Statement stat=con.createStatement();

        String dbop="INSERT INTO employees.workers (ID,First_Name) VALUES ('6',"+name+"')";
        stat.execute(dbop);
        stat.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: can you share the code at line number 75, where this NPE has occurred

Comment: brother i've mentioned above. The STRING DBOP line - @Lazycoder_007

Comment: *I've found the line generating the error.* - I doubt that is the statement causing the error. Createing a String variable will not generated a NPE. Even if "name" is null, you will just see "null" in the dbop string. Add some debug code after the statement to display the value of the "dbop" variable.

Comment: sorry for that, actually it is `stat=con.createStatement()` line that is generating the error

Comment: Ok, so which variable on that statement is null? Once you know that you can fix the problem.

Comment: clearly i think `con` is somehow empty. and if i am not wrong  `createStatement()` is not valid here? is it?